# Complex crypto investment puzzle

Tags: calculus

This is a real world problem that I am trying to solve:

Investor is presented with the opportunity to invest in either a crypto-currency (coin) or a mining operation that mines coins (share).  The investor may start by investing in a coin and then later, convert the coins into shares.

If we imagine that the cost of one coin is \$500, and the cost of one share is also $500, then the problem is as follows:

If the mining operation returns 0.0002 coins per day per share; and
Shares can be reinvested (compounded) for partial shares always at the same price of $500 per share; and
The value of each coin is appreciating at the rate of 5% per day; then:

What is the optimal strategy for the investor to maximize a $500 investment?

(I note that the complexities arise in part because the shares are sold in dollars, but the earnings are paid in coins.  Thus, as the coins rise in value, the daily mining returns also rise in value.  I can't figure out a solution).

There is a follow up question, which is: if the return from each full mining share declines at the rate of 4% per month (each mining share produces 4% fewer coins each successive month), how does that change the optimal investment?

Comment: This is the $13429.94 question.

Answer (score 0):

Owning coins is worth $5\%$ per day.  If a coin is worth $c$, owning a share is worth $\frac {0.02c}{500}\%$ per day.  It will be better to own coins when $5 \gt \frac {0.02c}{500}$, which is when $c \lt 125000$.  The switchover comes when $500(1.05)^t=125000$, which is after $113$ days.  I leave the followup to you.

Comment: Thank you for this answer!  However, I believe we are missing a material term.  As the 0.02c created by mining add a partial share in the amount of 0.02c/500 share, which partial share then mines more coins each day, this compounding element has to be incorporated in order to find the precise answer.  It is this part of the problem that I have been unable to solve.

Comment: I think you can ignore that.  You can buy and sell shares and coin any time you want, so you just want to know which asset is better to hold today.  The returns compound whichever asset you hold.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks again!